# Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code -1, Flutter

Tags: android-studio, flutter

I recently updated the `Android Studio`, After that project is not running.

```
flutter run -v

Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code -1

#0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:28:3)
#1      buildGradleApp (package:flutter_tools/src/android/gradle.dart:387:7)
#2      _asyncThenWrapperHelper.<anonymous closure> (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:73:64)
#3      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1134:38)
#4      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1031:19)
#5      _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:139:18)
#6      Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:680:45)
#7      Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:709:32)
#8      Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:524:5)
#9      _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:32:15)
#10     _completeOnAsyncReturn (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:290:13)
#11     _DefaultProcessUtils.stream (package:flutter_tools/src/base/process.dart)
#12     _asyncThenWrapperHelper.<anonymous closure> (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:73:64)
#13     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1134:38)
#14     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1031:19)
#15     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:139:18)
#16     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:680:45)
#17     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:709:32)
#18     Future._addListener.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future_impl.dart:389:9)
#19     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1126:13)
#20     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1023:19)
#21     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:925:7)
#22     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:965:23)
#23     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:43:21)
#24     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:52:5)
#25     _runPendingImmediateCallback (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:118:13)
#26     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:175:5)
```

Then I run `flutter doctor -v`

```
doctor --verbose
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.8, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.720], locale en-IN)
    • Flutter version 1.12.13+hotfix.8 at C:\Users\shiva\flutter_src\flutter
    • Framework revision 0b8abb4724 (8 weeks ago), 2020-02-11 11:44:36 -0800
    • Engine revision e1e6ced81d
    • Dart version 2.7.0

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\shiva\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.3
    • ANDROID_HOME = C:/Users/shiva/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b04)
    X Android license status unknown.
      Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK Manager.
      See https://developer.android.com/studio/#downloads or visit https://flutter.dev/setup/#android-setup for detailed instructions.

[√] Android Studio (version 3.6)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 45.1.1
    • Dart plugin version 192.7761
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b04)

[!] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2018.3)
    • IntelliJ at C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.3.5
    X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
    • For information about installing plugins, see
      https://flutter.dev/intellij-setup/#installing-the-plugins

[√] VS Code (version 1.44.0)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\shiva\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.9.1

[√] Connected device (1 available)
    • ASUS X00TD • J9AAGF11K219NMK • android-arm64 • Android 9 (API 28)

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Problem is with licensing and all, then I run

```
flutter doctor --android-licenses
```

!Error

```
A newer version of the Android SDK is required. To update, run:
usersDirPath\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\bin\sdkmanager --update
```

Then I run

```
sdkmanager --update
```

It shows up

```
Warning: Unknown argument -v
Warning: Could not create settings
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCliSettings.<init>(SdkManagerCliSettings.java:419)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCliSettings.createSettings(SdkManagerCliSettings.java:152)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCliSettings.createSettings(SdkManagerCliSettings.java:134)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:57)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:48)
```

**What I have tried**

Changing jdk version to 8
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/31116#issuecomment-529807607

Installing `Android SDK 26.1.1 (obsolete)`
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/51670#issuecomment-593068819

Even uninstalling the android studio completely and installing it again.

Help me solve this error.

Android Studio version 3.6.2

**Edit**

I somehow(re-install) manage to accept all the licenses, but the error is still same.

```
Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code -1
#0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:28:3)
#1      buildGradleApp (package:flutter_tools/src/android/gradle.dart:387:7)
#2      _asyncThenWrapperHelper.<anonymous closure> (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:73:64)
#3      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1134:38)
#4      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1031:19)
#5      _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:139:18)
#6      Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:680:45)
#7      Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:709:32)
#8      Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:524:5)
```

After running `flutter doctor -v`

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.9, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.720], locale en-IN)
    • Flutter version 1.12.13+hotfix.9 at C:\Users\shiva\flutter
    • Framework revision f139b11009 (12 days ago), 2020-03-30 13:57:30 -0700
    • Engine revision af51afceb8
    • Dart version 2.7.2


[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\shiva\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.3
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b04)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 3.6)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 45.1.1
    • Dart plugin version 192.7761
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b04)

[!] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2018.3)
    • IntelliJ at C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.3.5
    X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
    • For information about installing plugins, see
      https://flutter.dev/intellij-setup/#installing-the-plugins

[√] VS Code (version 1.44.0)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\shiva\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.9.1

[√] Connected device (1 available)
    • ASUS X00TD • J9AAGF11K219NMK • android-arm64 • Android 9 (API 28)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Comment: Some changes have been made, android licenses are all accepted now, but the error is still the same.please help

Comment: Cloning the Flutter directly using git solved the problem.